# How to use Database.Migration() after Database.EnsureCreated() EF Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I was working on a **Xamarin.Forms** application and using EF 6 targeting ***.net standard 2.0***. The application is live on app store with my DBContext class as follows.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly string _databasePath;

    // Hotworks related tables
    public DbSet<User> User { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserProfile> UserProfile { get; set; }

    public DatabaseContext(string databasePath)
    {
        _databasePath = databasePath;
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={_databasePath}");    
    }
}
```

Now, I have to add a new column to the **User** Table. For that, I have created a **.net core console application** and generated the migration folder using below commands.

```
dotnet ef migrations add Initial
dotnet ef update database
```

Then, I copied the generated Migration folder to my dbContext project and changed the **Database.EnsureCreated()** to **Database.Migration()** But, I'm getting **SQLite error 1: Table "User" already exists**. Any help? Code already in the production having **Database.EnsureCreated()** but now I have to migrate and update the database but, it is not working and always I'm getting the ***table already exist*** error.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @habib Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.0

Comment: From the official Microsoft EntityFrameowrkCore documentation on `DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated Method `:
`Note that this API does not use migrations to create the database. In addition, the database that is created cannot be later updated using migrations. If you are targeting a relational database and using migrations, you can use the DbContext.Database.Migrate() method to ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.`
[Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.infrastructure.databasefacade.ensurecreated?view=efcore-2.1)

Comment: One way to solve your issue is to manually update your database to be equivalent to the `Initial` migration, then edit the migrations history table (i.e. `__EFMigrationsHistory`).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a safer approach compared to my previous comment

1. `add-migration Initial` for the models that is equivalent to the production database (i.e. **without** the newly added column in `User` table and other changes that you did after deploying to production).
2. Manually update the production database `__EFMigrationsHistory` to include the `Initial` migration.
3. `add-migration XXX` for the updated schema (i.e. new columns, etc).
4. `XXX` should then be applied to your production database by the `Database.EnsureMigrate()` method.

Comment: Hi @Paolo, Thanks for the response. I ran the "dotnet ef migrations add Initial" without adding the new column in the model class and generated the "Migration" folder. After that I'm not able to understand how to update manually the database and add new column to User table. Also, I'm using EF core 2.0 version for Xamarin.Forms so, there is no method named "Database.EnsureMigrate()". Could you please elaborate a little so I can follow the steps and update the database.

Comment: @MayankShrivastava Try creating a temp database with the `Initial` migration and also created using `Database.EnsureMigrate`. examine its `__EFMigrationsHistory`, the row in that table should be manually inserted to your production database.